# Java sum 2 negative numbers

Tags: java, sum, plpgsql, negative-number

I'm trying to convert a function in java to pl/pgsql, and one problem that I found is when I'm trying to sum 2 negative numbers, and a get a positive number, more specifically :

```
public void sum(){
    int n1 = -1808642602;
    int n2 = -904321301;
    System.out.println(n1 + n2);// result is 1582003393
}
```

And in pl/pgsql I get an integer out of range error, and if I change the variables type to bigint i get a normal sum of 2 negative numbers, that is -2712963903, instead of 1582003393

How do I do to pl/pgsql get the same result without printing an integer out of range error?

Comment: I love questions where you just know the answers are going to pour in.

Comment: Specifically, the identical answers, entered within 30 seconds of each other. :)

Comment: use `long`,  know the boundaries of yer types.

Comment: We should really start down-voting/flagging all the identical duplicates, they just add to the clutter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because the Java int underflows and doesn't tell you.

To get the answer you are looking for in pl, you need to use bigint. Then detect the case when the result is less than Java Integer.MIN_INT (-2^31), which is the case where Java will give a positive result. To get what Java would give you, add 2^32.

Comment: To be fair, the question being answered was "how does Java sum the numbers." The question changed/evolved/clarified after that was answered. And that's okay.

Answer (score 2):

You are overflowing the `int` try the same thing with `long` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

It's overflowing, because the result is too big for an int. Use long instead.

Answer (score 1):

Java sums them as 32 bit signed integers, which wrap at -2<sup>31</sup>. Have you tried a 64 bit long instead?

Answer (score 1):

That valid rand of `int` in Java is `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647` (`-2^31 - 2^31-1`).

You are causing an Integer underflow. You should use a type `long` instead of int which ranges from `-2^63 to 2^63-1`

Answer (score 0):

Java treats those 2 numbers as signed integers.
Basically the scope for singed integers is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (-2^31 - 2^31-1). 
Hence the sum of those to values is -2712963903 which is less than the the minimum -2^31 so underflows and then wraps around by doing 2^32 - 2712963903 which gives you the signed int 1582003393.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a `long` which will not overflow in this case (but will for large enough numbers)

```
System.out.println((long) n1 + n2);
```