# VB .NET calculating differently to Java

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, math, encryption

Can someone explain to me why .net is calculating these differently to Java

The equation

```
(-1646490243 << 4) + 3333 ^ -1646490243 + -957401312 ^ (-1646490243 >> 5) + 4
```

Java calculates it as

```
1173210151
```

.Net calculates as

```
-574040108
```

My issue is that I need .Net to calculate the same as Java as i'm porting across a decryption function and if it calculates differently then the decryption isn't going to be right.

Any help would be appreciated.

**--Update--**

Thanks guys, Xor was what I should of been using. Plus need to workaround Java not throwing an exception when an Integer number is too big.

Xor gives a result of -3121757145

```
(-1646490243 << 4) + 3333 Xor -1646490243 + -957401312 Xor (-1646490243 >> 5) + 4
```

Combine this with the answer from this link I found - [Java sum 2 negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121698/java-sum-2-negative-numbers). Gives the same result as Java

```
-3121757145 + 2 ^ 32 = 1173210151
```

Comment: In Java, `^` is the `XOR` operator. I'm not familiar with VB, but some Google searches hinted that `Xor` is the xor operator and `^` is for exponentiation in VB. Might this be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the operator precedence table for [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and [Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), they're the same regarding the operators in the expression. So it's not a problem with precedence.

Be aware though, in Visual Basic `^` is the operator for [exponentiation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh100ckf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), whereas `Xor` is the operator for [exclusive or](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csw1x2a6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). That's different from Java, which uses the `^` operator as exclusive or and doesn't have an operator for exponentiation. All the other operators in the expression are the same in both languages

I can't tell from the code if the snippet is the one in Java or the one in Visual Basic - I'm guessing is in Java. If that's the case, it's quite possible that you've confused the exclusive or; try replacing `^` with `Xor` in the Visual Basic code and see if that fixes the problem:

```
(-1646490243 << 4) + 3333 Xor -1646490243 + -957401312 Xor (-1646490243 >> 5) + 4
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar. The code is the same in both Java and .Net. I'm dropping the equation in the "Watch" window of both IDEs while they're in debug mode.

I tried using "Xor" and the result is -3121757145.

To me it seems like something is going wrong in Java as the result it returns is a positive number.